# HTML input date, respond to chosen value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<p>
  <label for="checkInDate">Check-in Date:</label>
  <input type="date" class="date" id="checkInDate" min="2015-01-01" 
    value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
</p>
```

Is there a way to respond to when the user selects a date? Using jquery, on('click') fires when the element is clicked/focused, but not when I actually select a date.

I need to detect this event so I can set the check-out date to the day after the chosen check-in date.

Edit: I have the change event firing, so now I want to add a day to the check-in date and set the check-out date as that value:

```
var checkInDate = $(this).val();
var tomorrow = new Date(checkInDate);
tomorrow.setDate(checkInDate.getDate() + 1);
$('#checkOutDate').val(tomorrow);
```

Results in

```
The specified value 'Thu Feb 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `change` method.

```
$('#checkInDate').change(function(){
    //Do what you want here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an input value. So you should use jQuery's [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to track that.

Keep in mind you can use the same syntax as the `.click()` event. I.E. `.on('change')`